# react useState and array.map do not work correctly

Tags: reactjs

I saw a lot of similar questions and answers but still do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

I want to display array of elements.

```
const [unitLeaders, setUnitLeaders] = useState([])


let tags = unitLeaders.map(leader => {
    return <Tag closable={true}
                closeIcon={<CloseCircleOutlined/>}
                onClose={() => clearLeader(leader)}>{leader}</Tag>;
})


<Space wrap>
   {tags}
</Space>
```

add new element

```
const onClick = ({key}) => {
    setUnitLeaders([...unitLeaders, key])
};
```

remove selected element

```
const clearLeader = (leader) => {
    setUnitLeaders(unitLeaders.filter(item => item !== leader))
};
```

Adding is working fine, but when im trying to delete element I got invalid array displayed. What I did wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set keys for components.

Ref: https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists

```js
...
let tags = unitLeaders.map(leader => {
    return <Tag closable={true}
                key={leader}
                closeIcon={<CloseCircleOutlined/>}
                onClose={() => clearLeader(leader)}>{leader}</Tag>;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if state is updated tags is not updated.

Because updating state means 'component update', not 'component mount'.

So tags is inited at first => 'component mount' and not update forever.

To solve this problem, you need to use unitLeaders in return like below.

```
return (
  <>
    {unitLeaders.map((leader,index) => (
      <Tag
        key={index}
        closable={true}
        closeIcon={<CloseCircleOutlined />}
        onClose={() => clearLeader(leader)}
      >
        {leader}
      </Tag>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

I think it'll works now.